# How to select multiple options in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I have a `ListBox` associated to a user. The user needs to be able to choose one or more options and save these options in the SQL database, but I can save only one option.

When I created my form I used the "enable postback option" and in my "selecction mode" I have: `multiple`.

Here is my code:

```
//IN MY FORM

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ClLinea_1 seleccion = new ClLinea_1();
    DataSet ds = seleccion.sqlSelectLinea_1();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    ListBoxLinea_1.DataSource = dt;
    ListBoxLinea_1.DataTextField = "descripcion";
    ListBoxLinea_1.DataValueField = "id_linea_1";
    ListBoxLinea_1.DataBind();
}

// IN MY BUTTON 
protected void btnInsertaLinea_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClLinea_1 inserta = new ClLinea_1();
    inserta.SqlSeleccionLinea_1(int.Parse(ListBoxLinea_1.SelectedValue.),int.Parse   
    (txtUsuario.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to make sure mulitiselect property is set to true.

Then use something like.

```
foreach(var item in MyListBox.SelectedItems)
{
   int value;
   if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out value)
   {
      // insert to db here.
   }
}
```